# How to select all the elements in dynamically created child component in Angular 6?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

I am dynamically creating a child component with multiple mat-cards through parent component, I am trying to apply styles to all the mat-cards on a whole, but each mat-card is treated as a whole div. Any method to select multiple mat-cards/element in a child component?

Parent component code:
HTML

```
<app-feed-item *ngFor="let document of documents"
  [document]="document"
  [users]="users">
</app-feed-item>
```

Child component:
HTML

```
<div class="mainDiv">
   <mat-card class="feedDiv">
       ....
   </mat-card>
</div>
```

I want mainDiv to select all the available mat-cards/elements in the child component but instead, it selects each element. Thanks in Avance

Comment: have you tried applying styles to mat-card element? that probably selects all the card elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer. For people looking for the solution, I added another div on the top of the parent element and applied a class. Code below:

```
<div class="topDiv">
   <app-feed-item *ngFor="let document of documents"
      [document]="document"
      [users]="users">
   </app-feed-item>
</div>
```

Solution is very simple, I don't know how I couldn't think of this before asking here.

Comment: This could resolve your particular issue, but do not is the answer for the question "How to select all the elements in dynamically created child component in Angular 6?".